# Fixing if statement to stop movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, attr

**What I am trying to achieve**

The racer-offset is so that the user can set how far a image can move in px. The offsetted manages how far it has offsetted. Speed-racer tells how fast the Image can move during scrolling. My problem is it doesnt stop. I can provide a fiddle, but lets try first to see if this is easy to fix without it. Thanks.

HTML

```
 <img class="images" racer-offset="250" speed-racer="3" src="http://assets/img/fwman/FeeneyMan_bike.png" loc="576" style="left: 540px;" offsetted="924">
```

Javascript

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.images').each(function(){
        if($('this').attr('racer-offset') < $(this).attr('offsetted')){

        }
        else {
    var speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
    $('.images').css({left : "-="+speedR});
    $('.images').attr('offsetted', $(this).position().left);
    }
    });
});

   $('.images').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('loc', $(this).position().left);
   });
```

---

NEW VERSION

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(lastLeftLocation > $(document).scrollLeft()) {
        $('.images').each(function(){
                if($(this).position().left >= $(this).attr('loc')){
                console.log("0 == stopped");

                }
                else {
                speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
                $(this).css({left : "+="+speedR});
                $(this).attr('racer-offset') + speedR;
                $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('speed-racer') + $(this).attr('racer-offset'));
                }
            });
        }
    else {
        $('.images').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('racer-offset') <= 0){
            console.log("0 == stopped");
            }
            else {
            speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
            $(this).css({left : "-="+speedR});
            $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('racer-offset') - speedR);
            }
        });
    }


});
```

The only thing left to fix is I need speed-racer to add to racer offset in the if portion.

```
       $(this).attr('racer-offset', $(this).attr('speed-racer') + $(this).attr('racer-offset'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `this` inside quotes for some reason..

**$(this)** and **$('`this`')** are not the same.

```
if($('this').
```

supposed to

```
if($(this).
```

Comment: I think i need to change it around. What I need to do, is create a copy of racer-offset something called leftmovement, then subtract from racer-offset till it reaches 0. If it reaches 0, it stops, then goes back to counting up, meaning going the other direction not - but +.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this section of your code be:

```
var speedR = $(this).attr('speed-racer');
//$('.images').css({left : "-="+speedR});
$(this).css({left: "-="+speedR});
//$('.images').attr('offsetted', $(this).position().left);
$(this).attr('offsetted', $(this).position().left);
}
```

Caveat: Not tested though.